# Runtime error 5

Tags: excel, runtime

I am on Day one in learning Excel Macros. As per the tutorial I recorded the macros and tried to run it. (I have used the same file that they have provided in the tutorial and it is a .csv file)

But it showing me the following Error

> Runtime Error
>
> Invalid Procedure call or Argument

When I tried to debug it is showing as follows:

[image: Code]

Need Help

-Thanks

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/846166/solve-commandtype-0-error-in-excel   You can set the CommandType property only if the value of the QueryType property for the query table or PivotTable cache is xlOLEDBQuery. Is yours xlOLEDBQuery? Can you share the tutorial link? I guess if it works in the tutorial......

Comment: I am not sure about the query that you are asking as I am completely Novice in this. Here is the link of the tutorial https://www.guru99.com/introduction-to-macros-in-excel.html

Comment: What happens if you remove that line? Or comment out by placing ' in front of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the CommandType property only if the value of the QueryType property for the query table or PivotTable cache is xlOLEDBQuery, which is enum 5.

This is not the case for your query. In fact, that line doesn't even exist in the source code.  Perhaps you attempted to merge scripts? If so, be careful when merging connection code that the types are the same.

If you add in a debug line to get the [QueryType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.querytable.querytype)

```
Debug.Print .QueryType
.Name = "receipts"
```

you will get the enum 6 back. You can look this up using the object explorer:

[image: querytype]

As would be expected from the connection specification:

```
ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;
```